# Как полностью обезопасить работу с Mysql?

Tags: mysql, pdo, безопасность, взлом

В интернете я нашёл только один способ взлома Mysql базы данных - sql-инъекция. Однако там же я нашёл и решение, как не допустить попадание нежелательных символов в `mysql_query`:

```
$query  = sprintf("SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE somevar='%s'",
mysql_real_escape_string($var));
mysql_query($query);
```

И тем не менее, многие люди настойчиво рекомендуют переходить на другие расширения по работе с Mysql (PDO, например), считая оригинальное API априори небезопасным и недостаточно функциональным. На последнее я не жалуюсь, но безопасность важна для меня.

И вот вот вопрос: полностью ли меня обезопасил от хакерских атак код, приведённый выше? Если нет, то возможно ли мне обезопаситься полностью, не переходя на другие расширения?

Comment: расширение `mysql` для php официально признано устаревшим еще несколько лет назад (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php прям в красной рамке сверху написано). Если не ошибаюсь, в актуальных версиях PHP 7.*  оно уже отсутствует. Так что дело не только в том, что "люди говорят". Но на PDO переходить не обязательно, можно просто использовать mysqli аналогичным образом.

Comment: Сам недавно задавался подобным вопросом, и остановился на пдо.
http://phpfaq.ru/pdo Чуток инфы

Comment: В принципе обезопасили. От sql-инъекций. Но не обезопасили от проблем при переходе не другой хостинг, особенно в будущем, когда будет все меньше и меньше хостингов где в php будут функции mysql_*. Плюс к этому массовое выполнение запросов с разным текстом переполняет кеш запросов и ведет к деградации производительности сервера в целом. при использовании же pdo и bindParam этой проблемы так же нет, потому как текстов запросов не много, вместо параметров в текстах вопросительные знаки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если рассматривать ситуацию только в контексте "безопасность запросов от хакерских атак", то ответ: "Да, код, приведённый выше, полностью обезопасил от хакерских атак".

Однако при разработке остальные моменты тоже нужно учитывать

Answer (score 11):

Для защиты от SQL инъекций перейдите на расширение `PDO` или `mysqli` и воспользуйтесь функцией `bindParam`.

Функции `mysql_*` **устарели** и больше не поддерживаются.

**Пример использования для `PDO`**

```
<?php
   /* Выполнение запроса с привязкой PHP переменных */
    $calories = 150;
    $colour = 'red';
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
    $sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
    $sth->execute();
```

### [Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

**Пример для `mysqli`**

```
<?php    
    $sql = 'SELECT id, lastname FROM customers WHERE category = ? AND lastname LIKE ?';

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $category_id = 1;
    $lastname = '%Smith%';

    /* Bind параметры. Типы: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
    $stmt->bind_param('is', $category_id, $lastname);

    $stmt->execute();
```

### [Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Answer (score -2):

Нет, вы обезопасили себя не полностью. Вы не обезопасили себя от прямого подключения к вашему MySQL серверу. Ограничьте IP адреса, с которых можно подключаться к вашей базе данных - как в настройках пользователей MySQL, так и в настройках сетевого экрана.