# Двойные кавычки в БД не записываются не удаляются + режется строка

Tags: php, база-данных

Доброго времени суток! Мучаюсь уже несколько дней не могу въехать... Есть строки вида

> организация "Рога и Копыта"

не могу записать в БД ни с кавычками не убрать их никак вобще. мне не имеет значение

mysql_real_escape_string - не работает
addslashes - не работает

Записывает только организация (всё что до ковычек)

Помогите разобраться. ПС Одинарную кавычку записывает со слешами и выводит нормально.

ДОБАВЛЯЮ СВЯЗАННЫЙ КОД!

```
<form>
<input name="ololo" value="ооо"РОГА и КОПЫТА"">
<input type="submit">
</form>

$ololo= strip_tags(addslashes(trim($_POST['ololo'])));
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO table (ololo) VALUES ('$ololo')");
```

Comment: Код, с помощью которого записываете, в студию

Comment: $ololo = strip_tags(addslashes(trim($_POST['ololo '])));

Comment: Этот код явно не может ничего записывать в базу. Давайте весь код, связанный с записью, и не в комментарии, а в сам вопрос

Comment: @Vladislav_Carley, это `$ololo = strip_tags(addslashes(trim($_POST['ololo '])));` что-то из прошлого века! Из php4. Для работы с базой используйте PDO и **подготовленные выражения**. Ни какие `strip_tags()` и `addslashes()` вас не спасут.

Comment: @Visman: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD, потому что это не ответ, а 100500 дубликат, только предыдущий вопрос-ответ лень искать ;)

Comment: А если `value="ооо&quot;РОГА и КОПЫТА&quot"` так?

Comment: @andreymal, а в базу то это зачем писать? Это при выводе из базы пользователю делать надо.

Comment: В базу записывается выборка из select (в примере что бы не расписывать написал инпут) , а селект берется со стороны сервера через api  и там есть кавычки которые при записи в базу нужно или записать или удалить.

Comment: @Visman Весь прикол в том, что хоть вы и считаете что это 100500 дубликат, и может это даже так... Но я пересмотрел уже довольно много ответов на такие вопросы, и все как один отвечают в ключе mysql_real_escape ... Т.е. найти правильный, современный ответ по теме не представляется возможным среди тысяч морально устаревших

Comment: @Mike, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/559917/186083 подойдет?

Comment: @Visman Да, мне бы лично подошел :) Хотя там и текст вопроса немного в другую сторону, но ответ подойдет для данного вопроса. Ждем реакции ТС ...

Comment: @Mike, TC ждет готового решения https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683538/%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0?noredirect=1#comment1004810_683541 :)

Answer (score 1):

Оберните всю строку в одинарные ковычки

```
$string = 'организация "Рога и Копыта"';
echo $string;
```

На выходе

```
организация "Рога и Копыта"
```

Если внутри строки одинарные кавычки, оборачиваете в двойные

```
 $otherString = "организация 'Рога и Копыта'";
 echo $otherString;
```

На выходе

```
организация 'Рога и Копыта'
```

Если внутри двойные кавычки и строка обернуты в двойные, то экранируете внутренние двойные кавычки

```
 $otherString2 = "организация \"Рога и Копыта\"";
 echo $otherString2;
```

На выходе

```
организация "Рога и Копыта"
```

По вашему примеру

```
$ololo= strip_tags(addslashes(trim($_POST['ololo'])));
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO table (ololo) VALUES ('$ololo')");
```

Попробуйте вставить переменную $ololo по правилам конкатенации

```
$ololo= strip_tags(addslashes(trim($_POST['ololo'])));
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO table (ololo) VALUES ('".$ololo."')");
```

Замечание от пользователя @Visman

> Код этого ответа не безопасен, **возможны sql-инъекции**! Также функции mysql_ **устарели** и в современном php7 **отсутствуют**!

Comment: не работает! Оставляет всё до кавычек, остальное под снос...

Comment: Код этого ответа не безопасен, **возможны sql-инъекции**! Также функции `mysql_` **устарели** и в современном php7 **отсутствуют**!

Comment: Если вкурсе как при записи в бд удалить или записать кавычки поделитесь

Comment: @Vladislav_Carley Изучите примеры из описания этой http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php функции. И всегда используйте подготовленные запросы и привязываемые переменные

Comment: @Vladislav_Carley, я вам в комментарии к вопросу написал про PDO и подготовленные выражения, но вы видимо хотите готовый ответ.

Comment: @Visman, я так понимаю для этого сайт и создан

Comment: @Vladislav_Carley, значит ждите готовый ответ. Хотя документация всегда под рукой http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php