# Не срабатывает метод if (isset($_POST

Tags: php, post, методы

Добрый день, не могу разобраться. Почему код не работает POST методом... 
Если значения подставить явные значения (т.е.  $query = "INSERT INTO products (name, price, description) VALUE ('123', '123', '123')";) то код срабатывает как надо.
Помогите пожалуйста

```
<?php
define ('HOST',         "localhost");
define ('DB_USER',      "root");
define ('DB_PASSWORD',      "");
define ('DB',           "androidhive");

$response = array();

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description']; 

$link = mysqli_connect( HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB );

if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Не удалось подключиться";
    exit();
}
else {
    $query = "INSERT INTO products (name, price, description) VALUE ('$name', '$price', '$description')";

    if (  mysqli_query($link, $query)  ) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";
    }
    else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
    }
}
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**Добавлено**

```
<?php
define ('HOST',         "localhost");
define ('DB_USER',      "root");
define ('DB_PASSWORD',      "");
define ('DB',           "androidhive");

$response = array();

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {        
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
}

$link = mysqli_connect( HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB );

if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Не удалось подключиться";
    exit();
    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO products (name, price, description) VALUE ('$name', '$price', '$description')";           
        if (  mysqli_query($link, $query)  ) {
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Данные добавлены";
        } else {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Данные не добавлены";
        }
    }       
echo json_encode($response);    
?>
```

Прошу прощения, исправил несколько синтаксических ошибок. Вроде в БД стал добавлять, но добавляет одно и тоже (т.е. `{"pid":"8","name":"","price":"0.00","description":"","created_at":"2017-07-02 21:47:58","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}`) каждый раз, не имеет значения какие данные я подставляю в POST запрос

Ругается на - Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\wamp\www\sf\tconnect.php on line 22

```
$query = "INSERT INTO products (name, price, description) VALUE ('$name', '$price', '$description')";
```

Comment: Потому что запросы к БД нужно делать правильно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/559917/186083

Comment: Выполните хотя бы элементарную отладку - выведите промежуточные значения кода и посмотрите, где он у Вас ведет себя не так, как надо. Скорее всего не приходят параметры у post запроса.

Comment: Проблема именно здесь: if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];