# Фильтрация данных и массив. Безопасность

Tags: php, массивы, безопасность

Подскажите пожалуйста, 
получаю со сторонних сайтов некоторые данные php curlом и загоняю их в массив.
Этим данным не очень то доверяю в плане безопасности.

**Нормально ли** если получив данные в массиве, я буду их **проверять при выборке из массива**? не зависимо к примеру какой там ужас происходит в массиве, xss, инъекции и ему подобное...

Comment: Все зависит, что вы хотите в конечном итоге с этим делать, если выводить пользователю, то стоит и проверить как мне кажется.

Comment: Читайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/568971/186083 Еще про запись в бд https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/559917/186083