# Странная работа preg_match PHP 5.6

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Делаю регистрацию. Написал шаблоны для имени, фамилии и т.д. с помощью регулярных выражений. Делаю простую конструкцию:

```
<?php


$name = "Іван";
$surname = "Петренко";
$email = "petrenko@gmail.com";
$pass = "ivan123";

if (preg_match("/^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([a-z0-9_\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/", $email)){
    if (preg_match("/^[А-ЯІЇ]{1}[а-яії]{2,11}$/", $name)){
        if (preg_match("/^[А-ЯІЇ]{1}[а-яії]{2,11}$/", $surname)){
            if (preg_match("([A-z0-9-_]{6,25})", $pass)){

              // здесь дальнейшие действия с регистрацией

            }
            else echo "Pass error";
        }
        else echo "Surname error";
    }
    else echo "Name error";
}
else echo "Email error";

?>
```

И при таком раскладе оно мне выводит **`"Name error"`**, хотя как мы видим, что имя проходит по шаблону.

---

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так и как исправить. И правильно ли я делаю логику для регистрации?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы как бы работаете с кодировкой UTF-8, соответственно в регулярных выражениях следует указывать [модификатор](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) **u** для их правильного функционирования:

```
/^[А-ЯІЇ][а-яії]{2,11}$/u
```

И последняя регулярка у вас не регулярку

```
/([a-z0-9_-]{6,25})/i
```

P.S. Но такое ограничение на имена, фамилии, пароли, да и email есть зло!

Comment: А что вы считаете не злом?)

Comment: дак зачем ограничивать человека длиной пароля? может хочу я 30 символов, вам то какая разница, все равно хэш храните. Почему по вашему я не могу использовать в пароле спец символы (точки звездочки, запятые и прочие знаки), пробелы, или почему бы не использовать русские буквы, или непечатные символы? Имхо, максимум что вы пароле надо проверять - это минимальную длину. Ну или отсекать пароли равные логину, или там натуральному ряду чисел, то есть проверять сложность.

Comment: @Cactus, для имен, фамилий и паролей я бы вообще ограничений не ставил (кроме минимальной длины пароля как teran написал) кроме может быть управляющих символов. Для почты: наличие собачки, а дальше отправка письма на этот адрес для его подтверждения. Еще по паролям: лучше просить у пользователя не ввод пароля, а паролевую фразу, то есть минимум два слова разделенные пробелом. И минимальную длину фразы назначить не меньше 16 символов.

Comment: Хм, ну я проверка для имен сделал только ради того, чтобы не писали там что-то типа: `<script>while(1){alert("lol");</script>` :D. Но в общем, спасибо. Учту!

Comment: данные при выводе просто эскейпить надо, тогда пусть хоть что там себе пишут.

Comment: @Cactus, вывод данных в браузер через htmlspecialchars() https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571274/186083 и запись пришедших данных через подготовленные выражения https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/559917/186083