# Как применить preg_replace с учетом кодировки utf8

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Ребята, возможно не особо удачно составил оглавление вопроса, но суть заключается в следующем:

у меня есть строки вот такого примера:

```
Программа «Я пробую» (включает 3 smart-тренировки в течении 2 недель) в любое время, всего за 1650 руб., вместо 3300 руб.

Программа "Стройная весна" (включает 6 smart-тренировок в течении месяца) с 7.30 до 17.00, всего за 2499 руб., вместо 6000 руб.

Программа 'Стройная весна' (включает 6 smart-тренировок в течении месяца) с 7.30 до 17.00, всего за 2499 руб., вместо 6000 руб.
```

Мне необходимо обезопасить себя для отправки в json.

Для этого я хочу удалить все лапки в разных вариантах из строки.

Если я:

```
$text1 = preg_replace('/[\«\»\'\"]/', '', $text1);
```

То на выходе я получаю

```
Программа Я пробую (вк�ючает 3 smart-тренировки в течении 2 неде�ь) в �юбое время, всего за 1650 руб., вместо 3300 руб.
```

Как это исправить, а также мне необходимо укоротить строку на макс. количество символов до 128

Comment: А зачем "себя обезопашивать", ведь функция json_encode должна отлично заэкранировать и закодировать все сложночитаемые символы и на принимающей стороне соответствующие функции декодирования json отлично все развернут к исходному виду

Comment: а не проще `preg_replace('/[\«\»\'\"]/u', '', $text1)` ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Странная работа preg\_match PHP 5.6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692515/%d0%a1%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-preg-match-php-5-6), [Не корректное поведение preg_replace() в php utf8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/724824) и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто используйте нативный `json_encode`, он сам всё экранирует:

```
$str = "Программа «Я пробую» (включает 3 smart-тренировки в течении 2 недель) в любое время, всего за 1650 руб., вместо 3300 руб.";

$json = json_encode($str);

var_dump($json);
```

---

Чтобы укоротить строку, используйте `mb_substr`:

```
$str = mb_substr($str, 0, 128);
$json = json_encode($str);
```

Comment: Спасибо, наверное так и сделаю. Можете подтправить свой вариант что бы обрезать строку предварительно до 128 символов

Comment: А для mb_substr явно флаг utf-8 есть необходимость передавать?

Comment: @WhoIsDT нет, она сама кодировку определяет.

Comment: Если у Вас `mb_internal_encoding` не `UTF-8`, то да, нужно передать..

Answer (score 5):

добавьте `/u`

```
$text1 = preg_replace('/[\«\»\'\"]/u', '', $text1);
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

> u (PCRE_UTF8)
>       Этот модификатор включает дополнительную функциональность PCRE, которая не совместима с Perl: шаблон и целевая строка обрабатываются как UTF-8 строки. Недопустимая целевая строка приводит к тому, что функции preg_* ничего не находят, а неправильный шаблон приводит к ошибке уровня E_WARNING. Пятый и шестой октеты UTF-8 последовательности рассматриваются недопустимыми с PHP 5.3.4 (согласно PCRE 7.3 2007-08-28); ранее они считались допустимыми.